# Define a static resource EventSetter, to be implemented for each using object independently

Tags: wpf

I don't know if I've phrased myself correctly, so let me further explain. 
I have a lot of `ListViews` in my project. And they all use the same `ListViewItem` style, which is a pretty big chunk of code, so I keep it in `App.xaml` as a static resource, so I can just reference it from anywhere.
Now my issue is that, for each `ListViewItem`, I want to have a distinct `MouseEvent` handler. As much as I understand, these MouseEvents need to be defined in Style for ListViewItems.
So I went ahead and made something like this (in the App.xaml):

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <!-- A lot of setters -->
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="MyHandler"/>
</Style>
```

My question is, how exactly could I create a separate `MyHandler` for every object that uses this style.
Also, I am not really sure that this is the best approach, so other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Whether this is "*the best approach*" can't be told without knowledge about what these event handlers are supposed to do, and why they are different for different ListViews. And are you sure you really need ListViews, when there is also the simpler ListBox?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a distinct handler for every `ListView` that uses `ListViewItemStyle`, you can create an individualized style for that `ListView` which is [`BasedOn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.basedon) `ListViewItemStyle`:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <!-- A lot of setters -->            
</Style>

...

<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="MyHandler"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

In this way, your individualized styles inherit all the `Setter`s and `Trigger`s from `ListViewItemStyle`, but you can also add more on top of those.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this is what I did in the meanwhile.